# Nginx authentication except those on local network

Tags: authentication, nginx, basic-authentication

Coming from apache2 one feature I can not achieve; require authentication only to external access but free access to users on my local network.
Any ideas how to handle easily this scenario?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I've deleted my previous answer and would like to suggest a solution I've provided below*

I did a little search and found this solution to your problem - **In code, where you use `auth_basic` directive, make such changes**:

```
satisfy    any;
allow      10.0.0.1/8;   // give access for all internal request
deny       all;
auth_basic "....";        // your auth_basic code goes here
auth_basic_user_file ...; // your auth_basic_user_file goes here
```

How it works? `satisfy` directive implies that `any` or `all` from next coming access rules must be passed to give access to resource. You can find more details here: [satisfy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#satisfy)

This should fit your problem perfectly ;)

Comment: Tried to add a variable but it seems that nginx doesn't like it:
nginx -t
[emerg]: "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here

Comment: Do you use your authentication for whole server (in `server` block) or just in some `location` blocks?

Comment: in the "location /" block.

Comment: so try my new solution inside `location` block - it should work as you want :)

Comment: Could you update your answer to have a semicolon on the `allow` line and use `#` for comments? This will help newbies!

Comment: this also worked with gss_auth! using https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module