# nginx: not ask password for localnet + satisfy any cause 403

Tags: authentication, nginx, ldap

I try to solve problem similar to described here:

[Nginx authentication except those on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505799/nginx-authentication-except-those-on-local-network)

I protect all my site with ldap auth,

but I want one "location" to make available without
auth for localnet, so I have config like this:

```
server {
  auth_ldap "LDAP Authentication";
  auth_ldap_servers auth1;

  location /for_localnet/ {
     satisfy any;
     allow 192.168.0.0/16;
     deny  all;
#I try with and without lines bellow
     auth_ldap "LDAP Authentication";
     auth_ldap_servers auth1;
  }
}
```

It works as expected for "localnet(192.168.x.x)", but for
access from internet it shows error 403, if I open http://site/for_localnet/.

So I have to open "http://site" it ask password, and after that I can open
http://site/for_localnet/, so question how to force nginx to ask password
when I open "http://site/for_localnet/" from internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in bug in nginx 1.4.6 (default for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS).
It is described here: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/285